# Css issue with 2 divs

Tags: html, css, html-table

I had 2 divs in 1 div wrapper. Since I have put a table in the left column,
the right one just got under it..

Any help? 
[Here's the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DSrn4/)

Here the html:

```
<div id="contentwrap">
  <div id="content">
    <p>
    <div id="contlinks">
      <h2>Openingsuren</h2>
      <p>
      <div class="menukaart">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Maandag</td>
              <td><span> 11.<sup>30</sup> - 23<sup>.00</sup></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Woensdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 23<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Donderdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 23<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Vrijdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 02<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zaterdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 02<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zondag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 23<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Dinsdag</td>
              <td>gesloten</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </p>
        <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        <h2>Leveringsuren</h2>
              <p>
      <div class="menukaart">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Maandag</td>
              <td><span> 11.<sup>30</sup> - 22<sup>.30</sup></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Woensdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 22<sup>.30</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Donderdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 22<sup>.30</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Vrijdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 01<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zaterdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 01<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zondag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 22<sup>.30</sup></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="contrechts">
        <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        <h2>Routebeschrijving</h2>
        <p>
          <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2513.590720583988!2d4.7124239999999995!3d50.949781699999996!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x386d8d5f9b06161f!2sMerdin+2!5e0!3m2!1snl!2sbe!4v1395157948750" width="470" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
        </p>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here the CSS of the divs:

```
#contentwrap {
 min-width:1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#contlinks{

float:left;
width:480px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#contlinks a{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#contlinks a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:underline
}
#contlinks h2{

font-size:20px;
}

#contrechts{

float:right;
width:480px;
margin-right:5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#contrechts h2{

font-size:20px;
}

#contrechts a{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#contrechts a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:underline
}
```

And here of the table:

```
.menukaart {
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    width:450px;
    border:0px solid #3f7f00;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}.menukaart table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    width:450px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
}.menukaart tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}

.menukaart table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;

}.menukaart tr:hover td{

}
.menukaart tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#d4ffaa; }
.menukaart tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#ffffff; }.menukaart td{
    vertical-align:middle;


    border:1px solid #3f7f00;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
}.menukaart tr:last-child td{
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}.menukaart tr td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}.menukaart tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.menukaart tr:first-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What's the question? Also, your jsFiddle doesn't represent the code you've posted here.

Comment: I don't understand, your fiddle seems to have nothing to do with the code you posted in your question. Maybe you posted the wrong link to the fiddle? Also, since your question isn't really about the `border-radius`, you might want to consider trimming that part of your CSS down to make it more readable...

Comment: Well, the two divs should be next to each other, instead now the "right" div is under the left one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no any problem with your CSS; however problem was with HTML. since you used too many div to build the page. somehow one `<div>` `id="contlinks"` were not closed properly.

I've modified the CSS a little bit. you can see the working Demo. http://jsbin.com/faqulego/1/

Comment: One last question: It seems that my h2 from the left div is slightly higher positioned than my h2 from the right div. Although they have the same styling?

Comment: because under `<div id="contrechts">` you are using extra `h2` heading..thats why you are seeing different alignment.

Answer (score 0):

this is error: `<p>` empty and `<div>` disordered

correct:

html

```
<div id="contentwrap">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="contrechts">
        <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        <h2>Routebeschrijving</h2>
          <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2513.590720583988!2d4.7124239999999995!3d50.949781699999996!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x386d8d5f9b06161f!2sMerdin+2!5e0!3m2!1snl!2sbe!4v1395157948750" width="470" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="contlinks">
      <h2>Openingsuren</h2>
      <div class="menukaart">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Maandag</td>
              <td><span> 11.<sup>30</sup> - 23<sup>.00</sup></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Woensdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 23<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Donderdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 23<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Vrijdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 02<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zaterdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 02<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zondag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 23<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Dinsdag</td>
              <td>gesloten</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        <h2>Leveringsuren</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="menukaart">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Maandag</td>
              <td><span> 11.<sup>30</sup> - 22<sup>.30</sup></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Woensdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 22<sup>.30</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Donderdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 22<sup>.30</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Vrijdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 01<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zaterdag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 01<sup>.00</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zondag</td>
              <td>11.<sup>30</sup> - 22<sup>.30</sup></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
<style type="text/css">
  #contentwrap {
 min-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#contlinks{

float:left;
width:480px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#contlinks a{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#contlinks a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:underline
}
#contlinks h2{

font-size:20px;
}

#contrechts{
float:right;
width:480px;
margin-right:5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#contrechts h2{

font-size:20px;
}

#contrechts a{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#contrechts a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:underline
}
.menukaart {
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    width:450px;
    border:0px solid #3f7f00;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}.menukaart table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    width:450px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
}.menukaart tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}

.menukaart table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;

}.menukaart tr:hover td{

}
.menukaart tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#d4ffaa; }
.menukaart tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#ffffff; }.menukaart td{
    vertical-align:middle;


    border:1px solid #3f7f00;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
}.menukaart tr:last-child td{
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}.menukaart tr td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}.menukaart tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.menukaart tr:first-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
</style>
```